# Non-conservative field?

Tags: forces, work, vector-fields

A [conservative field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) is a function of position/configuration, what about a non-conservative field? It's a function dependent on what?

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your idea of a non-conservative field.  Here's a simple example of one:  $F = y\hat x$

Answer (score 4):

A conservative field is a vector field where the integral along every closed path is zero.  Examples are gravity, and static electric and magnetic fields.

A non-conservative field is one where the integral along some path is not zero.  Wind velocity, for example, can be non-conservative.  Basically in simple terms, if the field has a "swirl", it is probably not conservative.

Answer (score 2):

a conservative field can mathematically be defined as a field where every integral along any closed path return a value of zero, an equivalent definition a force is conservative if the curl (vector product of the del operator and the potential) of the potential is zero, that is the potential is irrotational. 
most forces are conservative; the most common exceptions are those relating to any sort of friction, because this depend on the direction of motion.